# CKEditor Media embed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, oembed

I have CKEditor 4.5 running on a Rails 4 app with the [Media Embed](http://ckeditor.com/addon/embed) plugin, and everything seems to be correct--except that the embed code for some oembed services is sometimes constructed so that the embedded media isn't visible.  In the example below, if I go into the db, source editor, or inspector and manually change the height in `<div style="left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 0px; .. >` to something non-zero, the video displays correctly.  It does this for some, but not all, oembed services.

```
<div data-oembed-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLKeZukedZo">
<div>
<div style="left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.2493%;"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pLKeZukedZo?wmode=transparent&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" tabindex="-1"></iframe></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there somewhere in the config or plugin file to change the height, or at least set a minimum height?  Or is this an iframely issue (CKEditor runs the oembed through a free iframely api by default, and I'd rather not have to get an api key for this project since the documentation seems to be lacking).  I'm not great with javascript, but I haven't been able to find anything in the plugin files for Media Embed or any of its dependencies that looks like it sets height.

In the CKEditor textarea itself, the video displays at the correct height, but once it's published it displays at 0px.  Is this just a CSS issue or something?

Update: I got an iframely API key, but it's just changed the problem.  I changed the embed_provider line in media embed's plugin.js to

```
CKEDITOR.tools.extend( widgetDefinition, {
            // Use a dialog exposed by the embedbase plugin.
            dialog: 'embedBase',
            button: editor.lang.embedbase.button,
            allowedContent: 'div[!data-oembed-url]',
            requiredContent: 'div[data-oembed-url]',
            providerUrl: new CKEDITOR.template(
                '//iframe.ly/api/oembed?url={url}&callback={callback}&api_key=[my api key]'
            ),
```

(obviously with my actual api key and no square brackets).  But now some things that were loading embeds before won't load at all, and some things that were not loading before will load partially.  eg, YouTube videos will load a placeholder in the editor and published embed link, but will not display even when manually expanded to a non-zero height as above.  Instagram posts will load a placeholder space for the image but fully load the caption text, where before I couldn't get the image at all.

[CKEditor's documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.embedBase.baseDefinition-property-providerUrl) gives the example

```
widgetDefinition.providerUrl = new CKEDITOR.template(
    '//ckeditor.iframe.ly/api/oembed?url={url}&callback={callback}'
);
```

[or](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-embed_provider)

```
config.embed_provider = '//example.com/api/oembed-proxy?resource-url={url}&callback={callback}';
```

while [Iframely's](https://iframely.com/docs/ckeditor) gives the example

```
CKEDITOR.config.embed_provider = '//iframe.ly/api/oembed?url={url}&callback={callback}&api_key=[your key here]';
```

Update 2: After talking with iframely support, the above problem with only loading text was a lazy-load setting that I've changed.  Now I'm back to the original problem, ie, the embed is there and playable, but loads at `height: 0px;`

Update3: Iframely support said that part of the problem was Rails' whitelist stripping out the inline position property, which I [added to Rails' whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942114/rails-5-whitelist-css-property-for-sanitize-helper), but the video is still loading at 0px height.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it would help you, but you can define the default value at `config.js`:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
   // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
   config.embed_provider = '//ckeditor.iframe.ly/api/oembed?url={url}&callback={callback}';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails needed a lot of properties added to the whitelist in order to get this to work.  In application.rb:

```
default_tags = Loofah::HTML5::WhiteList::ALLOWED_CSS_PROPERTIES.add('position').add('padding-bottom').add('max-height').add('max-width').add('left').add('top')
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_attributes = ['href', 'src', 'alt', 'data-oembed-url', 'style', 'allowfullscreen', 'frameborder', 'tabindex', 'id', 'text', 'class', 'data-iframely-url']
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else comes across this issue, I found a fix of sorts.

Looks like the embed is inside an iframe which has inline style height of 300px.

To get around this, I set the format of the div to '1080p', this gives the parent div of the iframe a class of 'embed-1080p'

I then use the following css selector :

```
.embed-1080p > iframe {
    height: 600px !important;
}
```

To make iframe children of that class have a forced height of 600px